# Google Drive File : com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders.getAuthenticateAsList

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

We had implemented a batch process that hadn't problems until now.

Since this afternoon, it have started to give an error and the process ends, leaving to process thousands of files.

As we could check, the process does not jump to the same file, it is completely random. It may be when it's processed the file 200th, 1000th, 450000th ...

This is the error that is giving us:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders.getAuthenticateAsList()Ljava/util/List;
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.handleResponse(Credential.java:245)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:992)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at com.EjecucionExpress.EjecutaExpress.obtenTamanios(EjecutaExpress.java:588)
at com.EjecucionExpress.EjecutaExpress.obtenTamaniosRaid(EjecutaExpress.java:701)
at com.EjecucionExpress.EjecutaExpress.doGet(EjecutaExpress.java:159)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

..............

In the line 588 of the  "EjecutaExpress" class, in the  "obtenTamanios" method, we have the code:

```
File file = service.files().get(fileID).execute();
```

This is the code implementation that we have to get the service for Google Drive.

```
public static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");

            -----------------------------------------------------------

            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountUser(emailID)
                    .setServiceAccountId(
                            "CLIENT-ID-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                            new java.io.File(
                                    "P12-FILE"))
                    .build();
            credential.refreshToken();

            Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
                    .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
                    .setApplicationName("New Drive Service").build();
```

Anybody knows why it happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Drive API is attempting to call [this function](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.18.0-rc/com/google/api/client/http/HttpHeaders.html#getAuthenticateAsList%28%29), which has only been available since version 1.16.

Which version of google-http-java-client are you using? We had a similar problem that was fixed by updating from 1.15 to 1.18.